# SSRS Encryption errors post reinstall services

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Initially, I installed and configured SSRS and backed up Encryption Keys, able to run reports successfully. Then I uninstalled the SSRS from the VM, dropped report databases, renamed the SSRS folder in ProgramFiles and restarted the VM too. Installed it again, backed up the keys and now the issue is coming up - It says - Could not connect to the server. Please check your network settings and try again later.

And the error log says this

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!crypto!1!08/19/2022-20:25:23:: i INFO: Initializing crypto as user: <service_account>
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!crypto!1!08/19/2022-20:25:23:: i INFO: Exporting public key
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!crypto!1!08/19/2022-20:25:23:: i INFO: Importing existing encryption key
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!1!08/19/2022-20:25:23:: i INFO: Registering 300  : CsrfTokenValidationConfig
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!1!08/19/2022-20:25:23:: i INFO: Registering 500  : WebApiOwinConfig
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!1!08/19/2022-20:25:25:: i INFO: Registering 600  : ODataWebApiOwinConfig
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!crypto!3!08/19/2022-20:26:33:: e ERROR: Decryption failed, Current user: <service_account> : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80090005): Bad Data. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090005)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at RSManagedCrypto.RSCrypto.DecryptData(Byte[] pCipherText, Boolean useSalt)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.SymmetricKeyEncryption.Decrypt(Byte[] data, Boolean useSalt)
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!library!3!08/19/2022-20:26:33:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.CannotValidateEncryptedDataException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.CannotValidateEncryptedDataException: The report server was unable to validate the integrity of encrypted data in the database.;
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!3!08/19/2022-20:26:33:: w WARN: [79whxc7r]: CSRF Token not generated due to exception:\n Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.CannotValidateEncryptedDataException: The report server was unable to validate the integrity of encrypted data in the database.
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!crypto!8!08/19/2022-20:26:34:: e ERROR: Decryption failed, Current user: <service_account> : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80090005): Bad Data. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090005)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at RSManagedCrypto.RSCrypto.DecryptData(Byte[] pCipherText, Boolean useSalt)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.SymmetricKeyEncryption.Decrypt(Byte[] data, Boolean useSalt)
```

I have already been through this and did all these steps individually, still with same error

1.Restart SSRS
2.Change the encryption key
3.exec DeleteEncryptedContent
4.Dropped and Changed Report Databases

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203955/the-report-server-was-unable-to-validate-the-integrity-of-encrypted-data) helps.

Comment: Yes, I have already been through this and did all these steps individually, with no luck

1.Restart SSRS
2.Change the encryption key
3.exec DeleteEncryptedContent
4.Dropped and Changed Report Databases

Comment: Ok. After trying different solutions, I fixed it. How? Opened it in a private browser and it worked. Why? Don't know.....Any thoughts?

Comment: It could be related to cache. We often have trouble trying to fix a problem in many ways just to find out the problem was fixed long ago and the undesired response that still remained was due to cache. Are you able to test it on a normal tab of another browser or the same browser on a different computer?

Comment: yes, it worked after the cache and temp files are cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Cleared cache, temporary files, browsing history...and it worked.